# Clear input for a specific form value?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a clear/reset button for a specific value on input type.
I tried to make a js function for it, but that function cleared all values of the input type.
**This is my html :**

```html
<div id="wrapper-body">
    <div id="kiri" class="btn btn-default">

    <div id="kiri1">
    <div class="btn btn-default">
        <form action="../php/termo_i.php" id="form_input" method="post">
        <table border=0>
         <tr>
                <td width=70>Tanggal</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text"  id="datepicker" type="text" name="datepicker" size=26> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Silo</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>

    <select name="silo" onchange="updateField(this.name, this.value)">
      <option>-</option>
      <option value="Silo 1">Silo 1</option>
      <option value="Silo 2">Silo 2</option>
      <option value="Silo 3">Silo 3</option>
      <option value="Silo 4">Silo 4</option>
      <option value="Silo 5">Silo 5</option>
      <option value="Silo 6">Silo 6</option>
      <option value="Silo 7">Silo 7</option>
      <option value="Silo 8">Silo 8</option>
      <option value="Silo 9">Silo 9</option>
      <option value="Silo 10">Silo 10</option>
      <option value="Silo 11">Silo 11</option>
      <option value="Silo 12">Silo 12</option>
      <option value="Silo 13">Silo 13</option>
      <option value="Silo 14">Silo 14</option>
      <option value="Silo 15">Silo 15</option>
      <option value="Silo 16">Silo 16</option>
    </select>
 <input type="text" name="silo" size="16" readonly="readonly" id="silo">
</td>
<td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="S1" name="S1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 1</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s1" type="text" name="s1" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check();"> </td>
               <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l1" name="l1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 2</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s2" type="text" name="s2" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check1();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
                <input type="text" id="l2" name="l2" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 3</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s3" type="text" name="s3" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check2();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
                <input type="text" id="l3" name="l3" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 4</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s4"type="text" name="s4" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check3();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
                <input type="text" id="l4" name="l4" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 5</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s5" type="text" name="s5" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check4();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
                <input type="text" id="l5" name="l5" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 6</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s6" type="text" name="s6" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check5();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
                <input type="text" id="l6" name="l6" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 7</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s7" type="text" name="s7" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check6();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l7" name="l7" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 8</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s8" type="text" name="s8" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check7();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l8" name="l8"  maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 9</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s9" type="text" name="s9" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check8();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l9" name="l9"  maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 10</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s10" type="text" name="s10" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check9();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l10" name="l10"  maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 11</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s11" type="text" name="s11" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeyup="check10();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l11" name="l11" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Sensor 12</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="s12" type="text" name="s12" maxlength="5" size=26 onkeypress="check11();onPress_ENTER();"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="l12" name="l12"  maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width=70>Ambien</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="amb" name="amb" value="35.0" readonly="readonly" type="text" size=26> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="amb1" name="amb1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled"style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Average</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="avr" name="avr" type="text" size=26 readonly="readonly"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="avr1" name="avr1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Defiasi</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="deff" name="deff" type="text" size=26 readonly="readonly"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="deff1" name="deff1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Status</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="sts" name="sts" type="text" size=26 readonly="readonly"> </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input type="text" id="st1" name="st1" maxlength="5" size=1 disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70></td>
                <td width=10></td>
                <td width=30>
                 <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Ok" name="ok" id="ok"
                 <span id="result"></span> 
                 <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset" > 
                 <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Save" name="save">
                 <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Delete" name="delete">
                 </td>
                <td width=1>
               <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Print" name="print"> 
                 </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btn btn-default" style="padding-left:350px">


    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Edit" name="edit">




    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is my js function :**

```js
// JavaScript Document
$("#ok").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#form_input").attr("action"),
         $("#form_input :input").serializeArray(),
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
   });
clearInput();
});

$("#form_input").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
function clearInput() {
    $("#form_input :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

I've try to change `$(this).val('') with document.getElementById('silo').value('');` and it did not work. I can't figure it out the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clearInput() {
    var a=document.querySelectorAll("#form_input :input");
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      a.value="";
    }
}
```

Comment: var a = will be get all range of the index of the item on :input? how i calculate the index? when the index of the item of my :input to much. can i change var a into the :item id?

Comment: sorry your question is not clear. edit the question and add your html code too

Comment: you are using different ids like s1 l1 etc. Change it into single type like s1 s2 s3 etc.

Comment: oh like that..  can i use this for call the item of the form type? 
$(document).ready(function() { // execute when everything is loaded
    $("#searchField").val("something"); // set the value
});

Comment: ya. You can also use `document.getElementById(id).value=""` instead of using `document.getElementById(id).value("")` because it is a property. not a function

Comment: document.getElementById(id).value="" or document.getElementById.value("") in JS when i use JQuerry like this right?
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#id').val("");

Comment: I said alternate method. You can eother use jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: i use jQuery $('#datepicker').val('');
calling the id's and it work. thx

Answer (score 0):

For each of those specific inputs, add a class `cls`
And change your `clearInput()` function like below

```
function clearInput() { 
         $("#form_input .cls").each( function(){
                   $(this).val(''); 
          });
}
```